# find values based on various interval conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a data similar to this where id visits a store every 6 months and a few of these visits included a visit in between (that is every third month) so a few of these ids visted six months and among them a few visited in between (3rd month ) as well , so im trying to find those who visted every 6 months who also visted in between that 6 month period (3rd month )

```
id     month_count
q1     3
q1     3
q1     3
q1     3
q2     3
q2     6
q2     6
q3     3
q3     3
```

I want an out  put where we can Identify id rows for the month_count of total 6 but in the interval of every 3 months .
as you can  see above for each id

```
id       month_count
q1       3
q1       3
q1       3
q1       3
q3       3
q3       3
```

tried various methods but could'nt figure this out , kindly suggest a way to go about this .

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to achieve in a bit more details? And share the code source of your best attempt that did not succeed?

Comment: what im trying to achieve was to be able  to find id rows where each id visited a particular store every six months and also during that six month they visited in between(3rd month) for a mid bi yearly meet (that is once  in betwwen every 6 month ) now from the list of ids I was able to note every three month visits  but im strugling to further filter the six months cummulative to obtain something similar to the above . and my failed sattemps where I used groupby based on diff() which  only got me 6 month visit which is not what I was trying to get .

Comment: you have to include all relevant columns and indexes in the problem. You have to indicate exactly why each row should be filtered or not

Comment: I apologise for not being clear . I have updated what I was trying to achieve .